# Dynamically inserting into a set

Tags: c++, set

I would like to know how to insert data into a set dynamically.
I have a text file with different points and i need to insert into the set dynamically as i will not know how many items will be there.

sample.txt

```
Point [3 4]
Point [5 6]
```

main.cpp

```
 set<Point> s_p2;
 if (strData.find("Point") != string::npos) {
   pos = strData.find("t");
   strData = strData.substr(pos + 2, 4);
   istringstream in(strData);
   Point temp_p;
   in >> temp_p;
   s_p2.insert(temp_p);
}
```

`s_p2` is the set container and the following set of codes are looped till the end of the file.

Q1: If I do this, will my set have only 1 item or multiple items of `temp_p`?

Q2: How can i print out the values in side the set?

.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Point &p2) {
    p2.setDistFrOrigin();
    out << "[" << setw(4) << p2.getX() << setw(1) << "," << setw(4) << p2.getY() << "]   " << setprecision(3) << p2.getScalarValue() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your edits completely changed the question, so the posted answers didn't make sense. I've rolled back to the original question; if you have more questions, then please ask them separately. To answer your new question: you need to declare member functions `const`, such as `type getX() const`, in order to call them on objects declared `const`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1: If i do this will my set have only 1 item or multiple items of temp_p

That depends. The set will only store unique  `Point`s, so if the `temp_p` are different each time, they will all get stored. The "uniqueness" of a `Point` is determined using the comparison function used for the set's ordering.
 Two elements `A` and `B` are equal if `A` is not greater than `B` and `B` is not greater than `A`.

> Q2  How can i print out the values in side the set?

You should define an `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p)` operator, and then use `std::cout`. For example:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p)
{
  return os << p.someMethod() << " " << p.someOtherMethod();
}
```

Then,

```
std::set<Point> pointSet = ....;
for (std::set<Point>::const_iterator it = pointSet.begin(); 
     it!= pointSet.end(); 
     ++it)
{
  std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

or, in c++11

```
for (const auto& p : pointSet)
{
  std::cout << p << "\n";
}
```

Comment: i have already created the  overloadig operator in my point class. but how can i print out the elements in my set

Comment: @user1571494 I added an example.

Comment: @user1571494 it doesn't mean anything. There could be a function that gives you a set full of points, or there could be some code that follows, where you fill in the elements.

Comment: I followed your inputs but i am getting the following error Assn3.cpp:166:17: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << it.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = Point, std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::reference = const Point&]()’

Comment: @user1571494 that means there is an error in your declaration and/or implementation of `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p)`.

Comment: i have updated the post with the codes of my overloadin ouput operator

Comment: Or, in C++98 (and maybe C++11), `std::copy(pointSet.begin(), pointSet.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Point>(std::cout, "\n"));`

Comment: @user1571494 Your operator does not take a `const Point&`, so you should use `iterator` instead of `const_iterator`. However, a mutating ostream operator doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @juanchopanza I know you would be furious with me. But i am very sorry i am still getting this error Assn3.cpp:157:17: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << it.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = Point, std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::reference = const Point2D&]()’

Comment: @ChristianRau Looking at my codes any idea where i went wrong. cause i cant print at all

Comment: @user1571494 are your getter methods const?

Comment: @juanchopanza So i need to make all my getter to const is it

Comment: @user1571494 yes, you should. A) they don't change the object, B) you are rightly passing `const Point&` to the operator. Non-const methods cannot be called on const instances.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks alot... Now i understand. const methods have to call const methods only. Right ?

Comment: @user1571494 they don't *have to* call anything, but they *cannot* call non-const methods.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks alot..u have been a super duper helpful.. Great

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all of your code works:

Q1- You will get multiple items inside the set because every time the code runs through the if a new temp_p is created and then copied inside the set when you inser it

Q2- You could use an **iterator** to go through the *set* and print its item:

```
set<Point>::iterator mySetIterator;

for (mySetIterator =  s_p2.begin(); mySetIterator != s_p2.end(); mySetIterator++)
{
   //print mySetIterator, where mySetIterator is a pointer to the n-th value of your set
   cout<<(*mySetIteartor);
}
```

Comment: But i am getting this error Assn3.cpp:166:12: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << mySetIterator.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator* [with _Tp = Point, std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::reference = const Point&]()’

Comment: If you have overwritten your operator <<, remember to dereference mySetIterator, because it is a pointer cout<<*mySetIterator;

Comment: `mySetIterator` is not a pointer: it is an iterator. If it were a pointer, operator `<<` would have happily printed the address it pointed to.

Comment: @user1571494 Why do you want to turn it into a pointer? An iterator is not the same as a pointer, but can be used the same way in many cases. Specifically, it can be dereferenced just as if it were a pointer. That part of il_guru's comment was correct.

Comment: @@Gorpik i cant seem to print out anything at all

Comment: @user1571494 Are you mixing `Point` and `Point2D` or it is a typo?

Comment: @user1571494 Your new error is probably related with method `Point::getX()`. which you haven't shown us. This method is probably non-`const`.

Answer (score -2):

> Q1: If i do this will my set have only 1 item or multiple items of `temp_p`

Since you're using a set container, which is defined to store unique keys, you will get a unique value of each point. If you were using multiset, then you'd have multiple values.

> Q2 How can I print out the values inside the set?

I agree with what juanchopanza wrote.

BTW: It seems, by looking at your code, that each point you read, the value that inserted is `[3 4` etc. Is that what you intended to do?